# how to get image-reflection in joomla?

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

i found one plugin, i installed in my joomla site. but can't get reflection eventhough i put the relative path in between  tags. please give appropriate solution and be greatfull by giving an answer!! thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html5 there is already define tags for shadow of image..but html5 is not supported by all browsers.. you have to wait till all browser support html5..

Answer (score 0):

you need to change to type of the image from gif to png.